# How do I recreate this case statement created in SAS within access 2013?

Tags: ms-access

How do I recreate this case statement created in SAS within access 2013?  I have tried IF THEN ELSE statements and I cant seem to get them to work

WHEN t1.LAST_CLS_BAL<100
   THEN "=5000
   THEN ">=$5,000"
   ELSE "ERR"

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use an iif statement.

iif(expresion, result1, result2)

Nested
iif(expresion1, result1, iif(expresion2, result 2, result3))